# Hover does not work with background-image linear-gradient

Tags: css

Searched for answers and tried everything. Why the hover does not work as written:

```
a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #018273;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #018273 0%, #00f2fe 100%);
}
a:hover {
  background-image: (to right, #15d9e4 0%, #018273 100%);
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the image gradient function name: `linear-gradient( to right... etc )`. There is no _shorthand_ for CSS's image gradient functions.

Answer (score 1):

i think its working i tried and was working well here is demo code i tried:

```css
a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #018273;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #018273 0%, #00f2fe 100%);
}
a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #15d9e4 0%, #018273 100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: So so weird. I tried everything. Clearing cashe and restarting live server checking and re-checking the code, but it simply does not work on my machine but it works in here. But thanks anyway, at least I know its not a css code itself.